# Setting default with getopts in bash

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to use a bash code to bring a few python codes together and want to be able to provide multiple options which accept values which you can enter in via command line. For this I am trying to use getopts but am having issue with trying to set default values.

I have looked online and seen this and similar questions have been asked before and I have attempted to use the answers such as the colon options after the main getopts code and placing a default value before, this has lead to the code below:

```
!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-f <string] [-r <string>] [-t <string>] [-o <string>] [-s <5|10> [-e <1|2|3>] [-b <string>] [-q <string>]]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

q = "30"

b = "15"


while getopts ":f:r:t:o:s:e:b:q:" p; do
    case "${p}" in
        f)
            f=${OPTARG}

            ;;
        r)
            r=${OPTARG}
            ;;

        t)
            t=${OPTARG}
            ;;

        o)
            o=${OPTARG}
            ;;

        s)
            s=${OPTARG}
            ((s == 5 || s == 10)) || usage
            ;;

        e)
            e=${OPTARG}
            ((e == 1 || e == 2 || e == 3)) || usage
            ;;

        b)
            b=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        q)
            q=${OPTARG}
            ;;

        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done

: ${q = 30}

: ${b = 15}

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${f}" ] || [ -z "${r}" ] || [ -z "${t}" ] || [ -z "${o}" ] || [ -z "${s}" ] || [ -z "${e}" ] || [-z "${b}"] || [-z "${q}"]; then
    usage
fi

b2 = ${b} + 2

echo "The following are your options."
echo "reverse read file = ${r}"
echo "forward read file = ${f}"
echo "type of file = ${t}"
echo "output identifier = ${o}"
echo "number of splits wanted (s) = ${s}"
echo "You have chosen to complete ${e} rounds of joining"
echo "Your have chosen that a consensus region of ${b} bases is needed for a match to be made."
if ["${e}" == 3]; then
  echo " For quality trimming you have select threshold cut off at ${q}"
fi
```

As stated above I have never used getopts before and would appreciate if someone could explain how I could correct my code to set default values for both b and q options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No spaces around `=` in shell assignments!

#### Wrong

```
q = "30"
```

#### Right

```
q="30"
```

The wrong code executes a command `q` with arguments `=` and `30`.  This wasn't what was intended.

Similarly with:

```
: ${q = 30}
```

which should be:

```
: ${q=30}
```

and related but somewhat different:

```
b2 = ${b} + 2
```

which could be either of:

```
b2=$((${b} + 2))
b2="${b} + 2"
```

(or a number of minor variants), but note that these have very different results.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that to me, now works absolutely fine. Always forget about how important spacing is in bash!